# Postfix: force a bounce to undeliverable individual recipient stuck in queue

Tags: postfix

It is possible to manaully delete messages from the mail queue.

```
B693A1601A9   154654 Thu Mar  1 16:20:22  username@domain.tld
                (connect to gmail.cm[74.125.224.168]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         username@gmail.cm
```

Would be removed by `postsuper -d B693A1601A9`.

Is it possible to manually bounce messages from the mail queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However, what you probably mean is to force-bounce a recipient, which is the real issue, not the message.

Asked before [elsewhere in 2011](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.postfix.users/PPEgOfWOT1w). After setting up Wietse's configuration below, you could `postmap`, `postfix reload`, and flush the queue, forcing that recipient/message pairing to slam into the new transport rule.

> Bob Proulx:
>   I have been trying to deduce if it is possible to force a message
>   waiting in the mail queue with temporary errors (domain name
>   resolution failures) to bounce right now instead of waiting for the
>   timeout.

Wietse says:

> It would be incorrect to force a message to bounce. Messages can have
>   multiple recipients. It would be more correct to force-bounce a
>   recipient.
>
> To flag a destination or recipient as undeliverable:

`/etc/postfix/main.cf:
     transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport`

`/etc/postfix/transport:
     typodomain.example        error:5.1.2 Bad destination system address`

> Flagging one recipient in a queue file as undeliverable requires a lot
>   of code that currently does not exist: 1) a way for postsuper to mark
>   as "expired" one recipient in the middle of a list of recipients, 2) a
>   way to extract from the defer logfile the record that says why that
>   recipient was not yet delivered for use in the non-delivery
>   notification, and 3) a way to mark that defer logfile record as
>   "deleted" so that the problem won't be reported again.
>
> Wietse

Answer (score 3):

Update for others landing here. It is now (since postfix 3.5) possible to force expire a mail in a queue with [`postsuper -e B693A1601A9`](https://www.postfix.org/postsuper.1.html)

We use the following steps:

```bash
if [[ $QUEUE_ID == *"!" ]] ; then
  # remove mail from hold queue
  postsuper -H "$QUEUE_ID"
  QUEUE_ID="${QUEUE_ID%\!}"
fi
if [[ $QUEUE_ID == *"#" ]] ; then
  # mail is already expired
  QUEUE_ID="${QUEUE_ID%#}"
else
  postsuper -e "$QUEUE_ID"
fi

# do not wait for next queue check but send the bounce immediately
postqueue -i "$QUEUE_ID"
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible, as there is only minimal need of doing manual queue management. There are configuration parameters for doing it automatically: http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html#deferred_queue and http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#bounce_queue_lifetime (but remember the fatal downside of reducing bounce_queue_lifetime)

The best way would be to notify the sender about the delay and just wait until it bounces on its own: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#delay_warning_time